# Visual Studio 2010 won't allow me to debug web application

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I have the .NET Target framework set to .NET Framework 3.5

When I try to debug with f5, i get the following message in a popup window:
"Unable to start debugging on the web server.  Mixed-mode debugging of x64 processes is not supported when using Microsoft.NET Framework versions earlier than 4.0."

Of course when I set the target framework to .NET 4.0 it works fine.  However my web server only supports up to 3.5 so I have to try and make this work with 3.5.

The closest match to a googled solution is found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409790.aspx

however when I try to follow the steps to change the platform to x86, the setting it tells me to change simply isn't there.  The closest thing is project properties -> Build -> Platform target, and that doesn't fix the problem.

What am I doing wrong?
THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is disable mix-mode debugging.  That is simultaneously debugging native and managed code.  That is what's causing the issue here.

- Right click on the startup project and select properties
- Go to the Debug tab
- Uncheck the box which says "Enabled unmanaged code debugging"

Comment: Thanks!  Mine was a web application, so I had to go to properties -> Web -> uncheck "Native Code" from the "Debuggers" list.